# Mixture of fixed and relative height possible?

Tags: html, css, height

This might be a stupid question but is it somehow possible to make the height of an element 100% - e.g. 200px.

I know this doesn't work but I mean something like this:

```
#div {height:100%-200px}
```

The reason I need this is because I don't want the element to start at the top of the page (header) nor end on the bottom (footer). I Know I can also do this with margin-bottom and margin-top,or through z-index, but I'd rather set a definive height for my element. I just want to know if if's possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: @Passerby : +1, was about to update my answer with this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if old-browser support is not an issue, you can use `calc`

```
height:calc(100% - 200px)
           /* ^^ ^^ these space are important!! */
```

For cross-browser, use it this way :

```
height:-webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
height: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
 /* mind the spaces around the operator, they are important 
   to let calc() operation happen */
```

Read more here :

http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: which value take by browser after giving two value {  calc(100% - 200px) } ?

Comment: @Nikhilkrishnan : browser takes `100%` of parent container and then does the calculation..

Comment: so what the purpose of giving 200px?

Comment: @Nikhilkrishnan : may be you should read question of OP...i wrote how it can be achieved...still if you don't understand, shall i give a practical example???

Comment: @NoobEditor- both item...can u add on fiddle ? or some helpful links?

Comment: @Nikhilkrishnan : check if you can understand anything from this fiddle  => http://jsfiddle.net/sQrUZ/

Comment: @Nikhilkrishnan : welcome..let me know if you still dnt understand!! ;)